# SQL in postgresql/php syntax error

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Here's my sql

```
$sqltable3=
'SELECT 
"Publications"."Pub_ID", 
"Questions"."Question" 
FROM "Publications" 
LEFT JOIN "Aspect_Pub_join" ON "Publications"."Pub_ID"="Aspect_Pub_join"."Pub_ID" 
LEFT JOIN "Aspect_question_join" ON "Aspect_Pub_join"."Aspect_ID"="Aspect_question_join"."Aspect_ID" 
LEFT JOIN "Questions" ON "Aspect_question_join"."Question_ID"="Questions"."Question_ID" 
Where "Publications"."Pub_ID"=$1 
GROUP BY "Questions"."Question" 
ORDER BY "Publications"."Pub_ID" ASC';
```

Here's the error:

> Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: column "Publications.Pub_ID" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "Publications"."Pub_ID", "Questions"."Question" FROM ... ^ in ...

I'm using Publications.Pub_ID in the order by as an aggregate function, so I'm not sure where I have gone wrong? The same query ran fine in mysql (I know it is less fussy).

If I take away the group by and order by functions then the sql runs, but obviously doesn't return the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to include Publications in the group by.

```
$sqltable3=
'SELECT 
"Publications"."Pub_ID", 
"Questions"."Question" 
FROM "Publications" 
LEFT JOIN "Aspect_Pub_join" ON "Publications"."Pub_ID"="Aspect_Pub_join"."Pub_ID" 
LEFT JOIN "Aspect_question_join" ON "Aspect_Pub_join"."Aspect_ID"="Aspect_question_join"."Aspect_ID" 
LEFT JOIN "Questions" ON "Aspect_question_join"."Question_ID"="Questions"."Question_ID" 
Where "Publications"."Pub_ID"=$1 
GROUP BY "Questions"."Question", 
"Publications"."Pub_ID" 
ORDER BY "Publications"."Pub_ID" ASC';
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear as it's asking to add another column in select list to your `group by` clause like below. Though don't see any reason why you need that `group by` since you are not using any aggregate functions

```
GROUP BY "Questions"."Question" , "Publications"."Pub_ID"
```